# QLabel border won't display with pixmap

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I can get a border to display on my `QLabels` just fine:

[image]

But when I try to display a pixmap in them, the border goes away:

[image]

I set the frame properties in the constructor of my `QLabel` subclass:

```
ObjectSlot::ObjectSlot(int index) {
    setIndex(index);

    setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
    setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
    setLineWidth(3); 
    setMidLineWidth(3);

    setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    return;
}
```

The pixmap is set in the `paintEvent`:

```
void ObjectSlot::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPixmap* image = new QPixmap("://images/Box.png");
    setPixmap(image->scaled(width(),height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
    QLabel::paintEvent(event);
}
```

Why does the border go away? Why is life so cruel?

Comment: The borders don't disappear just that you can't see it because the pixmap takes the size of the frame.

Comment: @NanaOsaberima With alpha channel image there are no borders too, so probably it is not a problem.

Comment: I tried using a smaller pixmap and had the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As doc said:

> Setting the pixmap clears any previous content. The buddy shortcut, if
>   any, is disabled.

So it seems that it is impossible, but I found next solution, you shouldn't `setPixmap()`, you need just `drawPixmap()` when all correct label was painted:

```
void ObjectSlot::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QLabel::paintEvent(e);
    //label painted
    QPainter p(this);
    QPixmap image("G:/2/qt.png");
    p.drawPixmap(QPoint(1,1),image.scaled(100,100,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
}
```

Result:

[image]

Not the best solution because you should adapt it to your purposes, but currently better than nothing.

Comment: This works nicely, thanks! Having to specify the pixel is a little messy though :)